# RF amplifier with square wave response

Tags: amplifier, rf, microwave

I want to amplify a 600MHz, 100pS rise time LVDS signal. This signal will be a pulse and I want to amplify each pair separately. If I use an RF amplifier like [MMG3H21](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMG3H21NT1.pdf), I guess it will add oscillations to the signal. I want to amplify the signal and it shouldn't disturb the rise time of the signal.

So I am asking what kind of amplification should i use to protect signal shape and rise time? Can a RF FET do the job for this application like [TAV2-14LN+](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/TAV2-14LN+.pdf)?

Comment: What output amplitude are you looking for and, at what current drive into a load?

Comment: Actually i want to feed an antenna with this signal.